# Change the owner of a file I can write to

Tags: files, permissions, chown

I have a folder called `fruit` with permission `777` and its owner is `fruit`.

I want to create a folder named `apple` under the `fruit` folder.
But I want to set this folder's owner as `apple`, not `fruit`.

However, I have only access of the `apple` user.

As the fruit folder is set to `777`, is it possible to do this using `chgrp`?

Answer (score 4):

`chgrp` is to "change the group ownership of a file or directory". Thus, you can't change user ownership with that command (use `chown` instead, which can change user **and** group ownership)

If your folder `fruit` is in 777 mode, obviously, anybody can create a sub-folder inside it. This sub-folder will be owned by the user who created it, so in your case, the sub-folder will be owned by `apple`.

Now, if your user `apple` wants to change the group ownership of one of his files, he has to be a member of that group. See:

```
$ id apple
uid=500(apple) gid=500(apple) groupes=500(apple,fruit,banana)
```

Then user `apple` could change his files or folders' group ownership to `apple`, `fruit` or `banana` but not to `cherry` since he's not a member of the `cherry` group.

Comment: seems same answer, same thoughts lol

Comment: @Maythux yep, but you're faster :) well done.

Answer (score 3):

The command `chown` needs root permission when transferring ownership to other users. `chgrp` is irrelevant since it only affects the group, not the user.

You can't obligate someone to take a file from you if he doesn't want. If you are a root or with root permissions then you are the commander and you can do whatever you want.

Instead as a workaround, you can create a group that held both user and give the ownership to that group so anyone of the users now has an ownership over it.